# How to find a file on Windows in linux using the terminal

Tags: files, windows, java

I have a .java file in Windows that I need to access in linux because it is a requirement of a homework project of mine to submit it to the school's linux server.  In the past, I've copied and pasted the text into vim in [noMachine](https://www.nomachine.com/) (linux virtual desktop) and saved it in my linux users home folder, but apparently I'm bot allowed to access noMachine off-campus and I won't be back on campus until after the due date. So I'm relegated to using [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) (terminal).

**TL;DR;** Is it possible to save the file in my Linux folder using just windows? If not, how do I access or save the file in linux using the terminal?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you able to SSH into the machine?

Comment: I'm not sure what that means. I'm very new to linux and networks and stuff. But SSH is the connection type if that's what you mean.

Comment: Right, so with SSH you can access your server remotely, provided you have the correct information such as your credentials for your user acct on Linux and the IP address of the server, and also in most cases a copy of your key (encrypted key)

Comment: Yes, I know how to submit the file once I have it, I just don't know how to access the file from the terminal in order to be able to send it. Can I access any of the files on my computer from the linux terminal? If so how?

Comment: See the answer below. You would need putty to do this

Comment: If you have SSH access you can use an FTP client like Filezilla and change the port to 22. Then transfer the file from your desktop to the linux server.

Comment: @에이바 you can't use FTP client to connect to an SSH server. A SFTP usually works though. Note however, that SFTP is not FTP over SSL - it is a completely different protocol.

Comment: @PsylentKnight Do you have a VPN Client and VPN Access?

Comment: `putty` is a ssh client for MS-windows.

Comment: Does putty have a file transfer mode. Openssh has `scp` copy over ssh, and `sftp` an ftp like interface over ssh. The implementation on the client, does not depend on any thing special in the server, just a normal ssh server. So was wondering if putty has something like this.

Comment: @peterph, I didn't say anything about SSL. I said SSH. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol

Comment: @에이바 I didn't say anything about OpenSSL either - note that OpenSSL and SSL are not the same thing. Very much like SFTP is not the same as FTPS. I just pointed out, that you can't use client speaking FTP(S) against server speaking SSH or SFTP. Well, you can - but it won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you've got access to the server using putty (going over ssh). That gets you logged in. After that just start vim, paste in the content as you would have done in noMachine (paste in putty is just right-click - at least for me). Then save the file from within vim.

I'm not sure if I'm missing a complication of your setup since this sounds very similar to what you must have been doing via NoMachine. If it doesn't make sense please clarify what doesn't work for you.

Comment: Thanks so much. Don't know why this didn't occur to me.

Answer (score 2):

Since you already do mention PuTTY, you already have all you need to find out how to [solve the problem](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=transfer+files+with+putty).

You have several options. One is using an SSH client (e.g. PuTTY) to connect to the server, running:

```
$ cat > path/to/resulting/file <<EOD
... your pasted text goes here ...
EOD
```

or just using a SCP client to just copy the file there. With `pscp` from the PuTTY suite, it might look like:

```
C:\...> pscp local\path\to\file username@linux.server:/remote/path/to/file
```